# Move the zoom to right bottom

Tags: plotting

I have a code that contains

```
ListPlot[{t13b, t21b, t30b, t41b, t51b}, 
PlotMarkers -> {{\[EmptyCircle], 7}, {\[EmptyUpTriangle], 
  10}, {\[FivePointedStar], 10}, {\[FilledSquare], 
  10}, {\[FilledCircle], 8}}, PlotRange -> {0.043, 0.046}, 
 PlotLegends -> { "13 beads", "21 beads", "30 beads", "41 beads", "51 beads"}, 
 PlotLabel -> "a_1 optimisation", Frame -> True, FrameLabel -> {"t_0", "E"}, Joined -> True, 
  Epilog -> { Transparent, EdgeForm[Thick], 
            Inset[ListPlot[{t13b, t21b, t30b, t41b, t51b}, 
 PlotRange -> {{0.40, 0.50}, {0.0452, 0.0456}}, Joined -> True, 
 Frame -> True]]}]
```

which plots

[image]

the plot in the middle is just a zoom in of the intersection, I wonder how to place it at the right corner, I tried using `placed` but it didn't work.
Thanks for any advice!

Comment: Have you seen the [`Epilog`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Epilog.html) docs? It use `{Right, Bottom}, {Right, Bottom}` as to stick an inset at the bottom right corder

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should add something like `Scaled@{0.8,0.1}` as second option of `Inset`
The numbers are the coordinates of the center of inserted sub-figure inside the outer graphics. Scaled form means the range {0,1} for both coordinates.

```
Inset[ListPlot[{t13b, t21b, t30b, t41b, t51b}, 
 PlotRange -> {{0.40, 0.50}, {0.0452, 0.0456}}, Joined -> True, 
 Frame -> True],Scaled@{0.8,0.1}]
```